# grid items should flow across rows, not columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid that contains 7 dynamically sized divs surrounded by 2 blocks that should align with the 2nd row of the 7 dynamic div grid.

I have it mostly working, except that the grid is orientated as columns and I want it to be rows. See fiddle, 1-7 should go across the top
https://jsfiddle.net/juzkxo20/5/

```
<div class='content'>
  <div class='left'></div>
  <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
    <div class='dynamic'>1</div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>    
  </div>
  <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
    <div class='dynamic'>2</div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
  </div>
    <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
    <div class='dynamic'>3</div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>    
  </div>
  <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
    <div class='dynamic'>4</div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
  </div>
    <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
    <div class='dynamic'>5</div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>    
  </div>
  <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
    <div class='dynamic'>6</div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
  </div>
    <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
    <div class='dynamic'>7</div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='right'></div>
</div>

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 7fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;  
  grid-gap: 10px;
grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.column-with-dynamic-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

.left {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row: 2 / 3 ;
}

.right {
  grid-column-end: -1;
  grid-row: 2 / 3 ;
}

/* just demo styles */
.left, .right { border: 2px solid red; }
.dynamic { background-color: lightgray;  border: 1px solid gray; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to solve your problem, I'm just now learning css grid, however I think most of this is correct.

You're .column-with-dynamic-content is creating a template with 7 columns, however, you only have 3 child divs inside of this container, it's looking for 7. You need this class to contain all 7 parent divs that contain the dynamic divs. I created a class below to show you.

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 7fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.column-with-dynamic-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.seven-children-column {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

.left {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.right {
  grid-column-end: -1;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}


/* just demo styles */

.left,
.right {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.dynamic {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
  <div class='left'></div>
  <div class='seven-children-column'>
    <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
      <div class='dynamic'>1</div>
      <div class='dynamic'></div>
      <div class='dynamic'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
      <div class='dynamic'>2</div>
      <div class='dynamic'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
      <div class='dynamic'>3</div>
      <div class='dynamic'></div>
      <div class='dynamic'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
      <div class='dynamic'>4</div>
      <div class='dynamic'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
      <div class='dynamic'>5</div>
      <div class='dynamic'></div>
      <div class='dynamic'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
      <div class='dynamic'>6</div>
      <div class='dynamic'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
      <div class='dynamic'>7</div>
      <div class='dynamic'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='right'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Grid provides [**line-based placement**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#line-placement), which allows you to define the size and location of grid items.

```css
.content, 
.column-with-dynamic-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;  
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.content > div:nth-child(1) { grid-column: 1 / 2;  grid-row: 2 / 3; }
.content > div:nth-child(2) { grid-column: 2 / 3; }
.content > div:nth-child(3) { grid-column: 3 / 4; }
.content > div:nth-child(4) { grid-column: 4 / 5; }
.content > div:nth-child(5) { grid-column: 5 / 6; }
.content > div:nth-child(6) { grid-column: 6 / 7; }
.content > div:nth-child(7) { grid-column: 7 / 8; }
.content > div:nth-child(8) { grid-column: 8 / 9; }
.content > div:nth-child(9) { grid-column: 9 / 10; grid-row: 2 / 3; }

/* just demo styles */
.left, .right { border: 2px solid red; }
.dynamic { background-color: lightgray;  border: 1px solid gray; }
```

```html
<div class='content'>
  <div class='left'></div>
  <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
    <div class='dynamic'>1</div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>    
  </div>
  <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
    <div class='dynamic'>2</div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
  </div>
    <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
    <div class='dynamic'>3</div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>    
  </div>
  <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
    <div class='dynamic'>4</div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
  </div>
    <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
    <div class='dynamic'>5</div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>    
  </div>
  <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
    <div class='dynamic'>6</div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
  </div>
    <div class='column-with-dynamic-content'>
    <div class='dynamic'>7</div>
    <div class='dynamic'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='right'></div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/juzkxo20/14/)

Comment: This is close, but for some reason the .content div is only as tall as the 2nd row (110px), therefore anything below isnt seen. The container div only expands to the 2nd row...make sense?

Comment: Yes, because the container's are set to content height. Do you want viewport height? https://jsfiddle.net/juzkxo20/17/

Comment: I would have thought it would grow to the height of the dynamic divs

Comment: I would need to know more details about what you're trying to accomplish in order to further modify the solution. But here's what's happening: The primary container (`.content`) creates two rows. The first natural row. And the second created by the placement of the edge boxes on the second row.

Comment: The nested container (`.column-with-dynamic-content`) exists only in the first and second rows of the primary container. Once the nested container has more than two items, it overflows the primary container. That's how this answer was set up. Once again, with more details about your overall goal, maybe a different solution is possible.