# Two-axis table layout with css-grid

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid

Resources like [complete-guide-to-grid on css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-grid-column-row) or [grid by example](https://gridbyexample.com/) are wonderful, yet I cannot figure out how to build a two-axis table layout.

The data for this layout is a simple weekly schedule, where each day has a `0-n` categories and each category has `0-n` dishes. The data looks something like this (pseudo-code):

```
DAY: { CATEGORY: [DISH] }
```

e.g.

```
monday: { a: [1, 2], b: [6], d: [5] },
tuesday: { b: [25], e: [0] },
...
friday: { a: [10], b: [9] },
```

The layout should look like this (note the empty top-left corner):

```
. MO  TU  WE  TH  FR
A a1              a10
  a2
B b6  b25         b9
D d5
```

Now, having spent years nesting `div`s to build layouts, I attempted to design this "layout-in", as is the mantra of css-grid, structuring the html in a way that is decoupled from the target-layout. See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/zeitwerk/pen/yvOMVq) for an example structure.

**My first attempt** was using grid-areas, like this:

```
.grid {
  grid-template-areas:
    ". 1  2  3  4  5"
    "a a1 a2 a3 a4 a5"
    "b b1 b2 b3 b4 b5";
    // ...
}
```

This "works", but now I have to create a class for every single cell in the table, which is silly.

**Then** I tried to create areas for each axis and one for the center cells:

```
.grid {
  grid-template-areas:
    ". n n n n n"
    "s x x x x x";
}
```

This does not work. Assigning `x` to each cell just stacks them on top of each other in the first `x` column/row, same thing with `n` up top. Also, the pattern does not repeat, so we end up with only two rows.

**Then** I thought about nesting grids, adding another grid under `n` and `x`. But this defeats the "layout-in" promise, so I decided against it.

**I believe I either fundamentally misunderstand areas, or what I am trying to do is not possible without nesting grids.** Any input, or an example two-axis layout using css-grid would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note that the Grid spec provides multiple methods for setting grid areas, sizing grid items, and aligning grid items. Using `grid-template-areas` is just one method, and it's not appropriate in some cases. For examples see my answers [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45459717/3597276) and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47229684/3597276).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with tabular data a `<table>` element might be more appropriate than trying to use css grid.

Comment: For structuring the markup I agree.
For styling the tabular data, I still need to use css, and here css-grid promises to work regardless of markup structure, which is why I want to use it.